# Working with Bash and cURL

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853407/how-to-get-correct-response-from-curl-in-executable-bash-script) here and got an answer that gave me what I needed.

I have a similar problem, but one that I can't find answer for so I'm asking another :/

When I run the following command directly in the terminal, I get the correct response when piped into jq.

```
curl GET "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2" | jq '.body'

RESPONSE: "*est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla*"
```

However, when I run the same command inside an executable bash script, I see no response?

```
result="$(curl GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2)" | jq '.body'
echo "$result"
```

The echoed result is an empty string.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction please, and possibly highlight some of the nuances with double/single quotations etc? I'm assuming I've making a syntax error?

Thanks

Comment: the pipe and jq also need to be in the subshell...

Comment: It isn't a nuance, it's quite obviously the only way it would work. Look up what `$()` does and how pipes work maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should process the results in jq inside the subshell.

```
result=$(curl GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2 | jq '.body')
echo "$result"
```

first pointed out by @123 in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable: result but never used it.

Comment: Updated my question, I was echoing it, just forgot to paste that into the question