# curl | jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have a simple bash file as below

```
    #!/bin/bash
    net=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" -d '{"network": {"name": "net1"}}' http://10.1.10.146:18090/network/v2.0/networks 2>&1 | awk '/id/{print $1}' | jq -r .network.id)
    echo $net
```

Running this file gives me an error as below

```
    parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
```

tried making the changes according to these links
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354943/setting-jq-output-to-a-bash-variable

[Working with Bash and cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889790/working-with-bash-and-curl?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but nothing helped me, unable to figure out where i am going wrong. let me know the reason for the error and possible changes.

The curl output for the command

```
    curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" -d '{"network": {"name": "net1"}}' http://10.1.10.146:18090/network/v2.0/networks
```

output:

```
    {"network":{"status":"ACTIVE","router:external":false,"availability_zone_hints":[],"availability_zones":[],"description":"","subnets":[],"shared":false,"tenant_id":"d0e75710820c401db3291ac6278f326f","created_at":"2018-05-15T07:37:42Z","tags":[],"ipv6_address_scope":null,"mtu":1450,"updated_at":"2018-05-15T07:37:42Z","admin_state_up":true,"revision_number":2,"ipv4_address_scope":null,"is_default":false,"port_security_enabled":true,"project_id":"d0e75710820c401db3291ac6278f326f","id":"1548df56-a35b-4232-9550-54a3c2266d60","name":"net1"}}
```

the idea is to get only the id from the output and store into a bash variable, to get the id i used the below command

```
     curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" -d '{"network": {"name": "net1"}}' http://10.1.10.146:18090/network/v2.0/networks 2>&1 | awk '/id/{print $1}' | jq -r .network.id
```

output:

```
    be831582-90c1-499c-875f-9c0b0d1969a6
```

I have also tried removing the awk and parsing the curl json response, the same error is showing up.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the `curl` output.

Comment: edited the question, now you can view the output of the curl in the question

Comment: Don't use `awk` at all. Let `jq` parse *all* of the JSON retrieved by `curl` for you.

Comment: Also note `curl` output contains DOS line endings. `jq` may not have any problem with that, but piping the output to other Linux utilities can produce surprising results.

Comment: @vidyadharreddy, no **just** the curl output. We need to see the raw JSON before awk and jq.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ...are you speaking to the specific API to OP is calling with DOS newlines? I don't understand DOS newlines in `Content-Type: application/json` responses to be standard convention (not asserting they're *invalid*, just that saying that "curl output contains" rather than "curl output may contain" might be a bit too strong).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , you are correct again. I'm still trying to work out where that statement of affirmative fact came from. "May" is indeed the correct qualifier for what cURL output can contain regarding `'\r'` terminated lines. I have been testing different servers retrieving pages, and it appears that cURL is returning the `'\n'` from almost all Nix based servers. I must have had IIS2 server response stuck in my head that led to the 'contains DOS line endings'. Good catch.

Comment: @glennjackman updated the question, now you see the raw json

Comment: @chepner i have removed the awk and gave a try, my file is as below :#!/bin/bash

net=`curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: $token" -d '{"network": {"name": "net1"}}' http://10.1.10.146:18090/network/v2.0/networks | jq -r .network.id`
echo $net the ouput is same error Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10

Answer (score 0):

The "parse error" message appears because the `2>&1` redirects any STDERR message into `jq`, which cannot parse it.  Compare the output from these commands:

```
> curl http://no.such.host/network/v2.0/networks 2>&1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: no.such.host

> curl http://no.such.host/network/v2.0/networks 2>&1 | jq '.'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4
```

Here are some ideas:

- Separate all of the piped commands into separate commands.
- Try adding `set -x` near the top of the script to "debug" all of the
  commands.
- Remove the `2>&1` because it is NOT helping you!
- Add error handling to the separate commands.

We could help more if you provided the curl output.  (We do not have HTTP access to the 10.1.10.146 host.)